# What are the correct constraints on UIScrollView from Interface Builder? Pure Autolayout from IB

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have been trying to get `ScrollView` to work for 2 days now, and it doesn't work at all. Most of the suggestions here on SO and other websites say that you need to pin the `ScrollView` to the `root view` and then place a `ContentView (UIView)` inside `ScrollView` and then pin it to all sides of the `ScrollView` (so that the `scroll size` can determine the `contentSize`... However this does nothing). There's also conflicting information out there, [one video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgeNPRBrB18&feature=youtu.be) says that there needs to be a constraint from the bottom of the `ScrollView` to the `ContentView`. Neither solution has worked for me. Here is what I've been doing in most of the combinations I've tried:

1. `UIView` -> `UIScrollView`
2. Pin all sides of the `UIScrollView` to the UIView
3. Create a `UIView` (name it `content view`) and `place` it inside `UIScrollView`
4. Pin all sides of the `UIView` to the `UIScrollView`

Problem at this point: `UIScrollView` needs `constraints` for `X` or `width` AND `Y` or `width`. The only thing that seems to solve the complaint is setting the `UIView` inside the `scroll view` centered horizontally and vertically, but this does nothing to make scrolling work. Another option is setting the `UIView` equal `height` and `width` to `scroll view`, but again, that does nothing other than remove the complaint.

I don't understand. Isn't pinning the sides, setting the constraints? `IB` seems to think that this is not the case.

What are the correct constraints needed? All I need is a simple view with stacked `controls` (to fill out a form) and the screen needs to be able to `scroll` if the form is longer than the `screen`.

I'm using iOS for the first time, and building purely from `IB` for now... minimal code solution would be best.

Comment: As the creator of the video you linked, I know for certain that it describes a working technique. Post screen shots of your layout and constraints. Maybe give a link to a test storyboard.

Comment: I confirm @robmayoff posted a correct and complete solution.

Comment: @robmayoff It works indeed. What I was missing was the Align Center X to View on the ContentView. It works now, thank you. It was added by accident...through "Add Missing Constraints".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are half way there. First you need to decide what you are going to display in the scrollview, you have placed a content view, that needs to have an intrinsic size. You can choose to put there static or dynamic views. Static views will have their size defined at design time, and that will resolve the UIScrollView AutoLayout constraints. If instead you are doing it at runtime with dynamic views you will need to choose a default size for your content view, create an IBOutlet for the width and/or height of your views and then resize them at runtime altering the outlet in viewDidLayoutSubviews. The video you linked explains that quite clearly.